# sqlite3 - keep open handler VS, open database when need

Tags: c++, unix, sqlite

How much overhead of `keeping sqlite3 database opened` VS. `open database only when need`.

The application is **high load**.

1) But it's hard to write version that will use one handler per thread, but I can write something like `driver` that will keep ie. 3-5 handlers opened and ready for reading and 1 for writing. Drive them for threads by request, keep mutexes etc. ( not easy solution to implement )

VS.

2) open sqlite database only when I need it by some thread and give sqlite to do all job, but here is additional overhead to open database each time.  (easy to implement)

**UPDATE:**
3) there are other option: I can keep one handler opened per database and use simple mutex to lock access to the database. The disadvantages of this is that I loose `concurrency reads`. So, only one thread will be able to read or write, while by option 3 there is `concurrency free reading` (more then 1 reader can read at the time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep it open.

Open and close file is more expensive then keep one file handler opened.

You can simulate the cost by running 1000 same queries in loop, 1st when open and close are inside the loop and then when you move them out.

Usually a multi-threaded application should use connection pool. The size of the pool should be calculated.

**EDIT:** synchronizing writes to DB can be done by `TRANSACTION`. in sqlite you use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `END TRANSACTION` sqls (or just `BEGIN` & `END`). `BEGIN` can be use as mutex lock in a loop, `END` can be use as unlock. it can protect you from altering the DB from other process.

**EDIT2:** more solution is connection per thread.

**EDIT3:** You can also implement or use a message queue to write to the DB.

**EDIT4:**
I think separating read & write is not so good idea, because write should be in higher priority than read. the problem is that in sqlite you can't lock a single table, you lock the entire DB.

When I used sqlite I used a wrapper class with a single handle to the DB, all the read and write from/to the DB by high level functions, I had a write queue, and also kept track for each table if it had unwritten change pending, so for every read function I could test if I have the updated data or should wait.

Comment: thanks, it's what I'm searching for about "file open" overhead. I add option 3 to the original post. So, 3 better then 2 ? ps. I will use sqlite to store `sessions`. As I'm already wrote application is high load and there is up to 200+ and more requests per second, but I will store last requested sessions on the memory for 15 minutes by app.

Comment: yes, I can store `old` sessions in one transaction to DB, I know this, but it's not able to use one connection per thread, because some threads service several databases (up to 200+ :) Maybe I must move to MySQL... but cons that it's another process to monitor etc.

Comment: yes, it's a good idea to use message queue to write, but the problem is reading by one handler, that can be also used to write. And application mean service the clients, so store the `old` data is not priority like read the data from DB and make the answer for waiting client...

Comment: Thanks you. I still thinking about what DB to choose... sqlite easy to use under c++. I look at mysql and it's have `hard` wrapper.

Comment: and thank you for your experience. seems it's will help not only me, because I'm already found this thread on the google :)